# Workflow 2010 is not firing when creating a new enterprise wiki page (on version 3)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, designer-workflow, enterprise-wiki

I have workflow 2010 which is responsible to populate a column value (Wiki Page Number), inside my SharePoint online enterprise wiki site collection, as follow:-

[image]

Now when creating a new enterprise wiki page inside SharePoint, the page will get version 3 after creating a new one. so inside the above workflow i define not to run the workflow unless the field is empty and the page version = 3. But in my case the workflow will never assign a value for the "Wiki Page Number" field when i create a new page. But if i re-edit the page and the page get version 4 or higher, the "Wiki Page Number" will be assigned. so not sure why SharePoint workflow 2010 does not get fired when the enterprise wiki page reaches version 3?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, when we create a new enterprise wiki page in SharePoint online, by design the version of this page is 2.0 instead of 3.0. As the below picture shows:

[image]

I think that's why the workflow doew not get fired. As a workaround, you could delete the condition `If current Item: Version not equals 2.0` in your workflow.

[image]

Comment: If i chose to update the wiki page while it is on version 2.0, then that will happen is that after saving the page i will get conflict error, since i will be updating the wiki page while the workflow assign the number,, that why i chose to do not update the filed unless the version =3.0